# Python default dictionary giving duplicate key

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, defaultdict

When i pass data in default dictionary in python, I get an out put as :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': ['1']})                          
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': ['1']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[6, 19, 32, 45]': ['1']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[3, 16, 29, 42]': ['1']})
```

How is it possible to get duplicate keys in the above output?

Shouldn't it be like

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': ['1', '1']})                          
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[6, 19, 32, 45]': ['1']})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[3, 16, 29, 42]': ['1']})
```

The code I am running is

```
def make_bands(value):
    d2 = defaultdict(list)
    for key, val in value.iteritems():
        d2[(str(list(val[0:4])))].append("1")

    print d2
```

**value** is another dictionary

The function `make_bands` is called to process Spark RDD as following:

```
signatureBands = signatureTable.map(lambda x: make_bands(x)).collect()
```

Comment: What's the full version of python you are using?

Comment: I seem to be able to build a dictionary with without this problem. can you reproduce this error with a small  example. this is what I tried: `[d[str(list([x, "en"]))].append("1") for x in "orson"]` where `d = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: That output obviously did not come from the code you posted - there are four ``defaultdict``s shown, the code only prints one.  Perhaps it came from four separate invocations of the code.

Comment: Python version Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)

Comment: To follow up on jason's question, is it possible that the code you pasted here is missing an extra indent before the `print` statement?

Comment: I have update the code. It is now exactly how I am running it and this reproduces the error.

Comment: Show us the code that calls `make_bands`

Comment: If it helps, the **value** is an Spark rdd of the form of key value pairs.

Comment: This is how I call it - signatureBands = signatureTable.map(lambda x: make_bands(x)).collect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, no, you cannot expect the output to be what you want it to be.  d2 is not kept between calls.  It's created anew every time you enter the function.  You can still get what you want if you use a class to keep the state, a generator (this will be less elegant here), or a function which constructs a function instead of a lambda (that would be my choice here):

```
def build_make_bands():
    d2 = defaultdict(list)
    def make_bands(value):
        for key, val in value.iteritems():
            d2[(str(list(val[0:4])))].append("1")
        print d2
    return make_bands
```

And then you'd call it like this:

```
 signatureTable.map(build_make_bands()).collect()
```

Comment: The make_bands is being called only once. And I need it to create a new default Dictionary if called again

Comment: The output I get from your code is 
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': [1]})                            
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[6, 19, 32, 45]': [2], '[0, 13, 26, 39]': [1]})
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[6, 19, 32, 45]': [2], '[3, 16, 29, 42]': [3], '[0, 13, 26, 39]': [1]})
    defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': [4]})

Comment: If the code in your question matches exactly the code you have, then `make_bands` is called 4 times.  `print` statement is outside the loop.  So it's only called once per call of `make_bands`.  And it doesn't have additional keys.  It has exactly 1 key at the end of the function call.  There is nothing to remove non-duplicate keys.  So the only thing to conclude is that `make_bands` is called once on each value (on `row`) of the RDD.

Comment: If you simply call `d2[str([0,13,26,39])].append('1')` twice (from Python command line without Spark), and then print it with `print d2`, you'll get what you expect: `defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'[0, 13, 26, 39]': ['1', '1']})`.  So the anomaly has to be due to how the data is stored across Spark clusters and what `collect` decides to do when what it gets is not an actual array.

Comment: Oh. I understood now. Thanks a lot!. I have now called a groupByKey on the map function. It gives me the desired output.